# How to convert these Days into integers?

Tags: pandas, date, type-conversion, integer, average

one question. I have a list under a column that looks like this:

`[<36 * Days>, <23 * Days>]
``
I would like to get only the values 36 and 23 as integers from this list (so that I can get the mean value from these two numbers for other purposes).

I have tried methods like this:

`df['tdColumn'] = pd.to_numeric(df['tdColumn'].dt.days, downcast='integer')` 
`df['tdColumn'] = df['tdColumn'].dt.days.astype('int16')`

But i keep getting AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Do you have an idea on how to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: I would be best to provide a reproducible example of your input ;)

Answer (score 1):

You likely have [`DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) You can use a list comprehension to access the repeat parameter:

```
df['tdColumn'] = [[x.n for x in l] for l in df['tdColumn']]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'tdColumn': [[pd.DateOffset(x) for x in range(3)]]})
print(df)

                                               tdColumn
0  [<0 * DateOffsets>, <DateOffset>, <2 * DateOffsets>]


df['tdColumn'] = [[x.n for x in l] for l in df['tdColumn']]
print(df)

    tdColumn
0  [0, 1, 2]
```

If you have a different Offset (e.g. days) you might need a different accessor (e.g. `.days`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'tdColumn': [[pd.DateOffset(days=x) for x in range(3)]]})
print(df)
                                                             tdColumn
0  [<DateOffset: days=0>, <DateOffset: days=1>, <DateOffset: days=2>]

df['tdColumn'] = [[x.days for x in l] for l in df['tdColumn']]
print(df)
    tdColumn
0  [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exctract attribute `n` in list comprehension, because there is list in columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'tdColumn':[[pd.offsets.DateOffset(36),
                               pd.offsets.DateOffset(23)]]})

df['tdColumn'] = [[x.n for x in l] for l in df['tdColumn']]
#alternative
df['tdColumn'] = df['tdColumn'].apply(lambda l: [x.n for x in l])
print (df)

   tdColumn
0  [36, 23]
```

Then for integer column use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = df.explode('tdColumn')
print (df)
  tdColumn
0       36
0       23
```

Another idea:

```
df = df.explode('tdColumn')

df['tdColumn'] = [x.n for x in df['tdColumn']]
print (df)

   tdColumn
0        36
0        23
```

Original solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'tdColumn':[pd.offsets.DateOffset(36),
                               pd.offsets.DateOffset(23)]})

df['tdColumn'] = df['tdColumn'].apply(lambda x: x.n)
    
print (df)
   tdColumn
0        36
1        23
```

Comment: Thank you on your prompt response. I get this AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'n'